# Can't Upload Subsequent DB versions to Azure - conflicts with existing version

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, webmatrix

Long time reader, relatively new poster :)

I've developed a PHP/MSSQL web app and I'm in the process of moving it onto Azure. So far I've just been using WebMatrix for web development and SQL Management Studio for the DB side of things.

The problem is, after my first push to Azure for the DB using WebMatrix, it can't upload future versions, since when it goes it upload it tries to drop all the tables, but can't because of foreign keys, existing primary key names, etc. Basically, because there is already previous copy of the DB on Azure, it can't upload my newer one. I don't want to keep what's on the remote DB, since it's still all just in testing.

Aside from writing procs to delete foreign keys, data, tables, etc. that I manually run before each upload, how can I get one-click deployment for the web and DB (ideally with WebMatrix or VisualStudio) to Azure so it just deletes the remote DB clean and uploads a new version each time?

Disclaimer: I'm not normally a web/DB dev, just working on a personal project for my side-business.

Comment: Can't you drop the entire database [`DROP DATABASE database_name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613(v=sql.120).aspx) before pushing to Azure?

Comment: I could drop it each time, but this would be a manual process. It would require me to re-create it each time, creating the web site user, and Azure may assign me a different hostname for the new DB, requiring me to update the connecting settings in my site. I'm hoping there's a way to just have this all done as part of 'one click' deployment, if not I'll just have to do this manually each time.

Comment: If you use the database project type in Visual Studio, you can compare versions (i.e. local to Azure) and just update the items that need updating. I use VS2012 and it works perfectly.